# Command-line completion while using the 'at' command

Tags: autocomplete, at

When entering commands into the `at>` prompt, I am unable to activate command-line autocompletion using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

```
$ at now + 4 hour
at>
```

Is there a way to turn on tab completion in the `at>` prompt?

I am using CentOS 7 and Bash with `at` version `at-3.1.13-24.el7.x86_64`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use your interactive shell's here-document feature to write the commands, and pass the result to `at` via stdin (rather than having `at` open and read stdin itself):

```
$ cat <<EOF | at now + 4 hour
> echo 'doing stuff now' >/tmp/foo
> EOF
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 22 at Wed Jun 10 16:11:00 2020
```

At least on my system (Ubuntu / bash 4.4.20(1)), tab completion works inside the here-doc - for completing the `/tmp/foo` filename for example.

Comment: Impressive. I wouldn't even have thought of trying that. Who uses that feature interactively? I would like to add that you can use `read -e` for that, too.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not:

```
 ldd /usr/bin/at
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd24182000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f70946ed000)
        libfl.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libfl.so.2 (0x00007f70946e8000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f70948f8000)
```

(My) `at` is not linked against `readline` (or something similar).